# Writing a Alexa (Localhost) Controlled Application in C#

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit, upnp

I'm trying to find out how i can build a uPnP C# Application which can be discovered and controlled by Amazons Alexa/Echo without having to build an AWS Skill. (So localhost ONLY).

I know that WeMo (from Belkin) is a Local device and can be found from Alexa without accessing the AWS.

So my Question is, how i can build my own "Wemo" in Software (without a Raspberry Pi or something)

Goal is to have a Windows Service Application.

Any Ideas? because i dont really know where to start.... :(

Comment: Your question is overly broad so it is likely to be closed rather soon. *"i dont really know where to start"* is not the right way to ask, instead try to come up with a way and see how far you get on your own.

Comment: Reading your comment, Ill get the idea you did only read the last line...

Comment: I can assure you, I read all of it.

Comment: If you know how to read Python, you could port [Fauxmo](https://github.com/makermusings/fauxmo) - software "faking" a WeMo

Comment: Maybe Alexa->Lamba->SQS->YourDevice->TakeAction
But I do not know how it could be done without internet..